# KGet: recovering connection after modem reset

Tags: linux-mint, kde

I try to use KDE now. Native download manager is **KGet** in KDE.

Problem is that KGet cannot continue file download, after computer (and modem) reload. It write that no connection. But Internet is working.

I used uGet before (in Ubuntu, Unity). uGet works good in KDE (Linux Mint) too. Maybe keep using uGet? 
Or is it possible to fix problem with KGet?